# Is it possible USB debugging when install apple OS on VMWare virtual machine?

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS developments. I do not have a apple computer so i decided to install apple OS in virtual machine.

I want to know is it possible plug ipad and load my testing projects or any other projects directly from xcode ?

I did not find proper solution for this when i searched through the internet.

Comment: You're better off buying an actual mac, doesn't need to be a fast one... as long as it has a reasonable amount of RAM (which is cheap, as long as you get a desktop mac). You can log into it over remote desktop from your Windows PC. OS X has built in support for VNC.

Comment: You can do so in VMware and download MacOS vmware image. Make sure you plug your iPad in USB2.0 , not USB 3.0.

Comment: @Abhi Beckert it is hard to buy actual machine in my country. price of a mac arround 2 lakhs (0.2 million) in here .That's why i'm tying to do this.

Comment: A secondhand mac mini is more like 0.02 lakh in most countries. I don't know how much shipping would be though. I assume you're planning to sell apps right? So that should pay for it. You can also rent a mac at, for example, macminivault.com

Answer (score 0):

Even when the previous answer is right, we do virtualize OSX in my company and works quite well. A little guide: http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-virtual-machine-vmware-inside-windows-7-or-windows-8/

Make sure the USB controller is enabled **in** the virtual machine.

Here is some info from VMware:https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/devices_usb_ws.html#1006715

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a VM to develop an iOS app and connect your iPad to the VM to debug your app. I am using ESXi 5.5 and added a new USB device while the iPad is connected to the host's usb controller. It shows as "Apple ipad" device. The iPad is recognized by the OS X VM.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately apple doesnt allow Mac OS X to run on a non apple hardware. So you won't be able to install Mac OS on virtual machine in a first place. There are various cracked versions available but those should be strongly avoided.

The best and recommended way to develop iOS application would be using proprietory Apple hardware with Mac OS and other relevant tools.

All the Best !!